# jQuery interactive scrolling crashes browser. I've run a debug after reproducing crash- and now I'm at a loss

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, parallax, crash-dumps

First a few things:

1. colourmagician dot com is the website in question.
2. The code I am using is from this tutorial (http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/create-interactive-street-view-jquery-9113038). There has been a post on here before about someone using the same tutorial, and experiencing flickering. (/questions/14502969/animation-flickers-with-firefox-18-0-1-due-to-requestanimationframe)
3. I have slightly modified a few values to achieve the desired effect I was going for. I am using a significant amount more images (for the video) than the tutorial/original website. I went in knowing my idea would probably falter as it is quite bandwidth heavy. Except it seems to have worked out alright.
4. The problem I have now (which you are able to reproduce yourself if you have time) is that when scrolling through, intermittently and occasionally it will start to stutter and the tab will crash.

-It crashes in Chrome fairly often, you'd be lucky to get through the whole website without it crashing.

-Firefox it has only crashed a couple of times. I haven't thus far been able to recreate the crash in IE, Safari and <strike>Opera</strike> (after some more testing its finally crashed in Opera) - they all seem to work okay.

1. I have debugged the chrome tab crashing. Here is an analysis of the dump if its any use (http://pastebin.com/X6MLfjNy)

So right now, it kind of works in Chrome. Stable-ish in Firefox and fine in everything else. Could this be a Chrome related issue?

Thanks for anyone who read through all this. If you have any thoughts or directions to point me I'd really appreciate it. (This is a project for University, I hope you enjoy it!)

Comment: I can't get Chrome to crash at the website mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'm sure if you give it a few more whirls it will though :(

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me in chrome until I hit the end of the "Intelligence is sexy" section. Then it fails to load "ntelligencevid/vid_00781.jpg" and your continue link points back to itself. Way too many images. Goodluck.

Comment: Thanks, that was just a minor hiccup when I transferred the site to a new server. There were a few frames missing, they've been uploaded. The last page isn't complete so I haven't linked up that button yet. (Just to clarify I don't think this is a part of the problem)

Comment: Fair enough. If you open your chrome dev tools and record some of your timeline, you'll notice alot of expensive paints going on. This tutorial on how to debug (http://addyosmani.com/blog/performance-optimisation-with-timeline-profiles/) may be helpful.